# Menu recommendation

Tags: jquery

Now I have discovered Jquery I'm in the process of updating my site. Could somebody recommend a Jquery menu system. Requirements.

1. Vectical & horizontal
2. CSS for styling
3. Three level minimum
4. Cross browser compaterble
5. Backwards compatible to IE 6
6. Nice and light

Thank you for looking.

Comment: IE6 is dead.  It is no longer supported by Google or Microsoft.  My most recent analytics data show it with a 1.5% share, which makes less important than Opera.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you may superfish jQuery plugin.

http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/

The menu structure should be in a standard ul li a structure

example

```
<ul class='menu'>
<li><a href="#">Company</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Styling needs to be done for ul.menu and superfish should be added to script and can be activated by

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
        $('ul.menu').superfish(); 
    });
```