# menus in html pages - separate navigation from content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When creating menus for html pages, there are a lot of libraries, frameworks and plugins (like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080837/menu-recommendation)). However, having studied various options it seems to me that

- the menu is a series of elements defined on one page which selectively are displayed/hidden
- all content activated by menu items is contained on one and the same page - together with all menu definitions

This brings, in my opinion, two problems:

- the (single) page tends towards "unmanageable" with growing size
- a search on something contained on the "third page" will result in the "first page" to be opened, and for a user it may not be obvious that he/she has to click through the menu to find what he/she was looking for

So I am looking for something where menu and content is more separated, but still makes use of the styling features of a modern framework (jQuery(UI), dojo, whatever), maybe on the basis of a JSON definition that can be loaded into each separate page.

Comment: "all content activated by menu items is contained on one and the same page - together with all menu definitions" - This sounds unlikely to me. I would expect most menu systems to expect each pages content to be on a different page, not all on the same page and hidden or displayed. Can you give an example of which ones you are looking at that do this?

Comment: @Chris for example http://dojotoolkit.org/widgets ... the source code is a bit horrifying

Comment: I'd say there is a tangible difference between tab controls (which is what seems to be on the link you provided) and menus. The one you linked from the other question seems to be an example of one that just restyles a `<ul>` to give it nice UI. I can't reccomend any specifically but I suspect those that you have been looking at have been tab controls rather than proper navigation ones. http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/36-eye-catching-jquery-navigation-menus/ is the top hit on google for "jquery navigation menus" and looks like it has a fair few options to look through...

Comment: @Chris if you'd make an answer out of it ... there seem to be enough hints in your link to take it from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making an answer as request. :)

The comments on your experience suggest that you ahve come across tab controls more than real navigation. Tab controls are designed to flip between content on the same page, hiding and showing content based on whcih tab is selected. This does have the drawbacks that you suggested of requiring all content to be on the same page (or to use ajax to load it).

Conversely a menu system will usually just be a way of formatting a bunch of links you give it, possibly with a hierarchical structure. Usually a menu system in the raw HTML will be an unordered list containing links and possibly other unordered lists. The exact format may vary depending on the menu system in use. The menu system will tell you to put classes on the top level or to run some javascript over a specific element.

In terms of generating this server side you are probably best off with either an include file or common server side code to generate the menus (to avoid having to maintain them individually in all the pages on your site).

Having said all that I have no specific reccomendations but I did come across http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/36-eye-catching-jquery-navigation-menus/ whcih was the top google hit for "jquery navigation menus" and has plenty of options to look at. Additionally the one in the question you linked looks like it is a "proper" menu system.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a huge menu option list, a tree structured `ul` won't be so heavy. You can have that menu on a different container, and the content in other, so it is not so unmanageable.

In the other hand, deploy the menu in a different HTTP call in order to get JSON data, and render it, could be more unmanageable than before. First, you need two HTTP calls, considering that the browser will issue only two HTTP calls to the same domain at the same time, to get the menu you are preventing the browser to get something else, or viceversa. You have to account the HTTP overhead, and that the menu query will be issued after the html and probably JS has been downloaded.

IMHO I think that the best performance is obtained keeping the html menu in the page code, and render it with CSS.

You can try to build it yourself. In the page's ready event, download a json menu data from the server with jQuery, build the html, apply the style you want and add it to the page.

Comment: agree with most ... especially your 4th para ... if there was something ready-made to support this approach I'd gladly look at it